Error while opening sensitivity labeled files with word web addin
I'm trying to open word files with word web addin in my local computer, not browser. There is no problem with regular word files, i can open and edit them. But when i try to open sensitivity labeled word file i am getting general exception error. Am i doing something wrong or is it not possible to open these files with web addin in local computer?
Here is the code i tried:
    async function insertDocument() {
        await Word.run(async (context) => {
           
            const externalDoc = context.application.createDocument(externalDocument);
            await context.sync();

            const externalDocBody = externalDoc.body;
            externalDocBody.load("text");
            await context.sync();

            
            const currentDocBody = context.document.body;
            currentDocBody.clear();
            await context.sync();

            
            const externalDocBodyText = externalDocBody.text;
            currentDocBody.insertText(externalDocBodyText, Word.InsertLocation.start);
            await context.sync();
        });
    }

    async function insertDocumentWithSettings() {       
        await Word.run(async (context) => {
            context.document.insertFileFromBase64(externalDocument, "Replace", {
                importTheme: true,
                importStyles: true,
                importParagraphSpacing: true,
                importPageColor: true,
                importChangeTrackingMode: true,
                importCustomProperties: true,
                importCustomXmlParts: true,
                importDifferentOddEvenPages: true
            });
            await context.sync();
        });
    }



I tried both of these functions but the result is same unlabeled files works fine but labeled ones not opening.
Here is the ss of error:

